# Are there any module options or techniques to authenticate through OpenAM on Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

I see that there is an OpenAM module for Drupal 7, but I do not see one for 8. Is there an option for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Port [OpenAM](https://www.drupal.org/project/openam) to Drupal 8 yourself.

Alternatively, [create a new issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/openam?categories=All) and wait until maybe someone else ported it.